# How to use groupBy in Bookshelf js?

Tags: node.js, angular, knex.js, bookshelf.js

how to use groupBy in **Bookshelf JS**, here is my Controller code.

```
router.route('/fetchStudentAttendance')
.post(function(req, res) {
 StudentAttendance
  .query(function (qb){
    qb.where('date', '>=', req.body.date);
    qb.groupBy("students_id");
  })
.where({'class_id': req.body.class_id, 'section_id': req.body.section_id})
.fetchAll({ withRelated: [{'StudentRef':function(qb) {qb.column('id', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name')}}]})
.then(studentAttendance => {
  let content = {
    data: studentAttendance,
    success: true,
    message: 'Record Not Found',
  };
  return res.send(content);
})
.catch(error => {
  let content = {
      data: error,
      success: false,
      message: 'Error while fetching Student Attendance.',
    };
  return res.send(content);
});
```

});

when i am trying to "groupBy" employee_id it will give Error like this.

```
code:"42703"
file:"parse_relation.c"
length:110
line:"3194"
name:"error"
position:"127"
routine:"check_ungrouped_columns_walker"
severity:"ERROR"
```

Comment: What exactly it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: In addition to answering fingeron's comment, for what reason are you saying `I am not able to use groupBy in Bookshelf JS`? What have you done so far to solve your problem? Have you looked at the documentation yet? What about the documentation are you finding confusing/lacking? http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-fetchPage has an example of `groupBy` in use.

Comment: What's the query that produces the error?

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR

Use Bookshelf's [built-in Collection manipulation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-groupBy) to do custom `groupBy` after the `.fetchAll()`
OR
Use raw Knex to generate your query and results as needed, since groupBy will require some SQL aggregation definitions. This can be a Knex query result, or a Bookshelf object.

More Words

Bookshelf isn't exactly a query generator; not like the query libray [KnexJS](http://knexjs.org/) it is built off of. Bookshelf is made as a way to collect rows from your DB as Object Models. A SQL "groupBy" clause is kind of custom to the query, and Bookshelf itself implements lodash methods, like lodash's `groupBy` as [stated in their docs](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-groupBy). However, that is a server-side grouping on the queried data, it is not using SQL to do so.

When using your `Model` in Bookshelf, you should use `new Model` or `Model.forge()` before you fetch (or in case of many, `.fetchAll()`). You can start a Knex query, in a way, by using `Model.query` ([see docs](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-query)), but be aware that is returning Bookshelf objects. I typically use `.query(function (qb) {})` to do some custom knex, like a custom `WHERE` clause or an `qb.orderBy('prop')`. Since `groupBy` would include 'many', you would want `Model.query().fetchAll()`, and be aware of custom aggregation in that query (Bookshelf will likely handle it, but it wouldn't be exactly like the model you defined, especially with custom methods). Using Knex directly might be a good option too.

Comment: Please edit your question with what you tried and what errors you are seeing. Bookshelf and "groupBy" is not like a SQL `GROUP BY` statement - so you'll have to be specific.

Comment: i edited my question, i get error when i am trying to "groupBy" employee_id.

Comment: You code is using the value of `req.body.employee_id`, did you mean "employee_id" instead? The column you want to group by needs to exist in your table.

Comment: i use "employee_id" but still got Error "routine: ""errorMissingColumn"""

Comment: Your code is looking for "employee_id" in the `StudentAttendance` model. What are the columns of the table that StudentAttendance uses? The error is pretty clear: the table used in the StudentAttendance model does not have a column named "employee_id".

Comment: sorry i am using wrong column, but when i am using right column (students_id), it will give an error "routine:check_ungrouped_columns_walker"

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, do one of two things, either:
1. Use `knex`, what Bookshelf is built upon, to run your `GROUP BY` query.  You might even want to build your query in SQL and run it, to make sure you're doing the correct things.
or
2.Do **not** do the `groupBy` in the Bookshelf model query, and use Bookshelf's built-in `groupBy()` on the returned collection (I linked in my answer). 
Good luck to you!